# Getting different javascript date in different region

Tags: javascript, date, region

If i run this code in GMT+5:30 it is Dec 1 2013

if i run the same script in GMT-8 it is some thing diferent.

**How can i get the same day(date) in both the regions?**

**JSFiddle Link:**

```
var date = new Date("2012-12-01");

alert(date);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/achieverprince/6RfWY/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you're in another region, then perhaps the default format in the second region isn't `yyyy/MM/dd` but `yyyy/dd/MM`. To avoid this problem, try this:

```
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 1);

alert(date);
```

Hope this helps.

[EDIT]

The Month parameter should be from 0 to 11 (0 is January and 11 is December), according to the [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) specification.

Comment: @achieverprince: What date is it giving then?

Comment: problem is not with month and date.. its with the time zone

Comment: @ProgramFOX using _Date_ that way has months starting from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @achieverprince: I edited my answer. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that *Date* refers to the same time in every timezone, work in *UTC*.

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 12 - 1, 1)); // months start 0
console.log(date.toUTCString());                // Sat, 01 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT
```